# Protractor tests for meanJS admin pages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, protractor, meanjs

Is there a way to create a [Protractor](http://www.protractortest.org) test in [meanJS](http://meanjs.org/) for the admin only pages? On this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/meanjs/mean/issues/1829), it explains that you have to modify the database to have an admin user.

Right now, all the example Protractor tests in meanJS start by signing up the user in the GUI before proceeding with the tests. But since there isn't a GUI method of signing up an admin, I don't see a way to test those pages automatically.

Is there a way to seed the test database beforehand?

I am seeing something called seedadmin in config\env\test.js and wonder if that's something I can somehow use in the E2E tests, too.